# What is maximum resolution of an image that can be loaded in UIImageView in iOS Devices?

Tags: ios, ios7, uiimageview

What is the maximum resolution of an `UIImage` that can be set in `UIImageView` using `SetImage:` method in iOS Devices?

Comment: Depends upon your imageVIew's frame

Comment: It can load any resolution image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load any size of image in a `UIImageView` as long a there is memory free.
But it is not the `UIImageView` that is taking up the memory, but the `UIImage`.

As  Apple states the following in the [`UIImage` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIImage) you should not load to big an image:

> You should avoid creating UIImage objects that are greater than 1024 x
>   1024 in size. Besides the large amount of memory such an image would
>   consume, you may run into problems when using the image as a texture
>   in OpenGL ES or when drawing the image to a view or layer. This size
>   restriction does not apply if you are performing code-based
>   manipulations, such as resizing an image larger than 1024 x 1024
>   pixels by drawing it to a bitmap-backed graphics context. In fact, you
>   may need to resize an image in this manner (or break it into several
>   smaller images) in order to draw it to one of your views.